# Only GDScript available on Godot on MacOS

Tags: godot, godot4

Whenever I add a new script to any of my nodes the only language I can choose in the dropdown menu is GDScript. According to the documentation there should be C++ and C# available additionally from scratch.

[image]

How can I add further language options for my existing project?

I'm using Godot 4.1.3 on MacOS 14.1.1 (M2 Chip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you downloaded the default package, instead of the mono version.
C# is only supported with the mono version. (Can't say what happened to C++ though.)

The Mono version can be found [here](https://godotengine.org/download/macos/), in the "all downloads" section.

Comment: Indeed that was it. With the mono version C# is available too. Unfortunately C++ is still not available for unknown reasons.